# What is the proper statistical analysis to use when accounting for replicates and different time-points?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, variance, multiple-comparisons, residuals

I have a set of data I need to analyze, and it is my first time doing this and my advisor isn't sure what to do either, so some guidance would be really super. For my project, I tested groups of seeds under certain treatments - the seeds were not individually tracked, but tracked as groups.

There were 3 groups of seeds (1 control and 2 different treatments), with 10 replicate groups each (for a total of 30 groups), and all were periodically checked over 4 time-points for a change in phenotype. At each of those times, seeds that showed this certain new phenotype were removed from the group, and the remaining seeds were left to be checked at the later time points. The independent variable is the control/treatments (which is consistent), with the dependent variable being how many seeds have the phenotype at each time. I'm not sure what the best way is to account for time-points and replicates.

This project resulted in the numbers of seeds that displayed the phenotype (i.e., P) at each time-point, and numbers of seeds that never displayed that phenotype by the end (i.e., no change or NC). What I'm interested in is how these seeds' phenotypes change over the points in time -- both between time-points for a singular treatment, as well as between all treatments over time. To this end, I am using a ratio of P over NC minus the P of the previous time point to get a more accurate reflection of how the number of seeds displaying the phenotype changes over time, since the pool for P reduces after each time-point.

A Levene's test on the data's variance is significant. A Q-Q plot of residuals shows deviation from the plotted line as well - so I did a log10 transformation to account for variance and the Q-Q plot is now as it should be, though the Levene's test is still significant. I read that the Q-Q plot is more reliable, so I proceeded with using a linear mixed model, as there may be "three levels" to consider in the analysis (dependent variable = log10 ratios -- fixed effect variables = timepoint AND treatment --- random effects grouping factors = replicates) . But, my analysis software (JASP) gives me this note: All random slopes involving "Treatment" have been removed for the random effects grouping factor "replicate". Factor "treatment" does not vary within the levels of random effects grouping factor "replicate". It states there are too few observations to estimate random slopes for timepoint for the grouping factor. Additionally, some ratios for between treatments are extreme (0/300 vs 299/300) at certain time-points, and they aren't considered significant, so I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Is using a linear mixed model proper for this? If so, would I still be able to use a Tukey post-hoc comparison to determine which groups actually differ?

Or would something else be better?

Thank you!

Comment: Damn, it sounds complicated. Supports the idea of thinking about the data analysis before you start the experiment. But … is it really that complicated? What are you trying to determine? Is time period 4 the most important? And the other time points provide rate information?

Comment: You can use a model for count data (number of seeds are counts) instead of log transforming the counts in order to treat the outcome as continuous. In a way, the experimental design suggests survival analysis as seeds are removed once after the event of displaying the phenotype. But also if the seeds are treated together (in the same "container") then seeds within a group are not independent..

Comment: Yeah - here on out I'll definitely be thinking of data analysis first! I'm basically trying to determine if each treatment has an effect on the proportion of seeds with that phenotype in each group, and/or if it causes a delay in the phenotype's occurrence, so every time-point is potentially just as important. I think a count data model could work be a good thing to look into. The seeds within a group are definitely not independent, maybe I can look into survival analysis methods and see if I can find a good fit. Thank you both!